# TypeError: Cannot read property 'googleplus' of undefined in IONIC with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I've been following these links to use social login in my hybrid app.

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus

https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/google-plus-login-with-ionic-framework

I've created all the google developer id's and all that stuff. I've installed the cordova-plugin-googleplus using those two as they said. But still my application showing the error i mentioned as header of this message...

> In this line:  window.plugins.googleplus.login(

So, please help me with this one... I've stuck on this for 2 dayzz...Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked this article http://ngcordova.com/docs/common-issues/?

Comment: For Ionic projects you can wrap plugins calls in the $ionicPlatform.ready() handler.

Comment: Thanks for your help...
Can you please post the code to how to check it...

Comment: did you get the solution for this @ SV Madhava Reddy. I am stuck at the same point

Comment: No yaar....But as one of my frnd suggest me like use hello js..It has all the functions in built...All the social logins in one place..Just go for it...

Answer (score 2):

Here below is an example of cordova plugins check in the [`$ionicPlatform.ready()`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/) function wrapper:

```
mainApp.run(["$ionicPlatform", "$window", function ($ionicPlatform, $window) {

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        if ($window.plugins && $window.plugins.googleplus) {
            $window.plugins.googleplus.isAvailable(
                function (available) {
                if (available) {
                    // show the Google+ sign-in button
                }
            });
        }
    ...

    }
```

PS: [`$window`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/) is an Angular wrapper for `window`

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByBTmKPo-Y2wQWtKdU1GRmhtQWs/view?usp=sharing

still got the same error...See the image above...

Comment: please post your code and project settings (config.xml, plugins/android.json)

Comment: [Android.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByBTmKPo-Y2wdzdBX1NJczFLUTg/view?usp=sharing)

------------------------------

[Config File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByBTmKPo-Y2wVXhmbFd2S0gyR1E/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm having the same issue, were you able to figure this out?